# C++ Using an object of a class within a function of that class

Tags: c++, oop, class, constructor

Say I have a header file that looks like:

```
# filename: header.h
class myclass
{
 public:
    int myVariable; # arbitrary member variable
    foo(); # arbitrary function
    myclass() # default constructor
}
```

Now lets say I want to implement my constructor [ myclass() ] in some .cpp file:
Can I do something like create an array, of objects, ints, anything - just some array.
And then can I loop through that array and fill it up **all from within my constructor definition?**

The reason I ask is because I want my arbitrary member function foo() to be able to change this array. This leads to the problem - am I passing an object of myclass into foo [ foo(myclass myclassObject) ?

Or do I pass this object's array into foo() ?

Any clarification on this would be much appreciated. I tried to make the example as non-specific to a certain case as possible, but still descriptive enough for everyone to understand the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create and "fill up" an array from within the constructor so it can be used by `foo`. Indeed, that is the purpose of the constructor (to set up everything for you).

Do note that if you want `foo()` to be able to use the array, you must make the array part of the class definition.

**myclass.h**

```
class myclass {
    private:
        int* arr; // declared on the "heap"
    public:
        foo();
        myclass(int arraySize);
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <stdio>

myclass::myclass(int arraySize) :arr(new int[arraySize]) {}

myclass::foo() {
    // prints the elements of the array we declared earlier
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int[] arr` - You can't leave an array size unspecified.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was just about to ask about some of the syntax and saw you updated it just as I was about to add a comment.

Comment: Tony - for my problem the size of the array will be constant, but what would be a solution if I could not determine the size until run time?

Comment: @TonyD Thanks. I work with both Java and C++, so sometimes I get confused.

Comment: @Joker you can pass a value to the constructor. I modified my code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor can indeed create an array - the question is what happens to that array after the constructor returns.

- A reasonable approach is to save it on the heap - i.e. create the array with `new[]` - but that means you'll need to keep a pointer to the array to access it afterwards.  Easiest way to do that is to add a pointer object to your class member data.  `foo()` can then access the array using that pointer.  Unfortunately, you must use either custom copy constructors, assignment operators and destructor (google Rule of Three) or a smart pointer to ensure proper copying or sharing and destruction of the array.
- Your question implies to me that you don't just want an array data member, which is of course the easiest solution.  Disadvantages with that are that the array size must be chosen at compile time, whereas heap based arrays can be sized at runtime.
- If you create it on the stack, then it will leave scope and be inaccessible afterwards (any attempt to access it via pointers or references set while it was in scope will result in undefined behaviour).
- It's also possible for a constructor to populate data in a static array, but clearly the array's lifetime is then independent of any single object instance of the class.  You've talked about the constructor creating the array so presumably don't want to do this.

Comment: I really appreciate this - find it very descriptive. I found out I **bold**do**bold** want an array data member, I just didn't know how to declare it until I realized I did know the size of the array.